# Angular: how to check the data type of component properties?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

"@angular/core": "^4.0.0"

"typescript": "~2.3.3"

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: '<app-child [data]="test"></app-child>'
})
export class ParentComponent {

  test: number = 123;
}

/****/

class Test {
  name: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: '<div></div>',
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() data: Test;
}
```

Why does ChildComponent not swear that the data property does not belong to the Test data type?
How can typescript or angular be able to check the incoming properties of a component?

Comment: I think feel the same. I think angular does not do it automatically

Comment: I am guessing that it's a runtime error and cannot be caught at compile, as nothing says that you will use these components together.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `instanceof`

```
if(data instanceof Test) {  console.log(true); }
```